# React-redux: proper way to navigate between child components and parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, components

I am new to react-redux. In my react-native app, I have an `Auth` component which is used by screens and imports `Login` and `SignUp` components, each represents login and signup pages. When the user clicks on SignUp, I want to show the `SignUp` component.

Auth component:

```
import Login from './login'
import SignUp from './signup'
import { showSignUpView } from '../../actions/index';

class UserAuth extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.centerView}>
                {this.props.authStep == "login" ? (
                    <View>
                        <View>
                            <Login navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
                        </View>

                        <View>
                            <Text style={{marginHorizontal: 10}}>or</Text>
                        </View>

                        <View>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.showSignUpView()}>
                                <Text>Sign Up</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                ):(
                    // props.authStep == "signup"
                    <View>
                        <SignUp navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
                    </View>
                )}
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      authStep: state.auth.authStep
    }
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {showSignUpView})(UserAuth);
```

In my action's index.js, I have the `showSignUpView` function

```
// brings user to signup page
export const showSignUpView = (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: "GO_TO_SIGNUP_PAGE"})
}
```

and in my reducers, I have the case for signup page:

```
const initialState = {
    authStep: "login"
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "GO_TO_SIGNUP_PAGE":
            return { ...state, authStep: "signup"}

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work and gives me the error:

```
dispatch is not a function. (In 'dispatch({
  type: "GO_TO_SIGNUP_PAGE"
})', 'dispatch' is undefined)
```

What is the proper way to do this? I also want to add a back button within `SignUp` page that brings the user back to main Auth component. What is the best way to accomplish that? Since Auth is a component and not a screen, I suspect `props.navigation.goBack()` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
export const showSignUpView = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: "GO_TO_SIGNUP_PAGE"})
}
```

which is the same to this in non-arrow-function way (the way it is documented in `redux-thunk`'s docs)

```js
export function showSignUpView() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: "GO_TO_SIGNUP_PAGE"})
  }
}
```

**Side note**

To navigate between screens (if i did not get it wrongly, you are using `react-navigation`), i find it much more awesome to do it with `react-navigation`'s navigators. Checkout the [Authentication Flow in their docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html)

Comment: Thanks! According to the doc you linked, seems like `Auth` here should be a screen instead of a component

Comment: Yes and no, it should be both a screen(in your navigator) and (created as) a component ;) [Checkout their docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html) to understand more. Btw, i was assuming you are using `react-navigation` because of the `this.props.navigation` in your code, did I get it right?

Comment: Yeah I am using react-navigation